# How do I return different response based on result of Future?

Tags: scala, spray, akka-http

I have login endpoint that looks roughly like this

```
get {
  (path("token") & parameters("email", "password")) { (email, password) =>
    complete {
      DBManager.getUserByEmail(email) match {
        case Some(user) =>
          // Check everything is return something
          UserWire(user)
        case None => StatusCodes.NotFound -> "User doesn't exist"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`DBManager.getUserByEmail` returns `Option[User]`. I just switched to Slick where everything is asynchronous thus method now returns `Future[User]`.

How can I send desired response when future has failed ? I tried this

```
    complete {
      DBManager.getUserByEmail(email).map(user => {
        // Check everything is return something
        UserWire(user)
      }).recoverWith { case ex => Future.successful(StatusCodes.NotFound -> "User doesn't exist") }
    }
```

It fails to compile with

```
Error:(497, 26) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Product with Serializable]
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
          }).recoverWith { case ex => Future.successful(StatusCodes.NotFound -> "User doesn't exist") }
                         ^
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spray you can use [`onComplete`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/), it gets a future and returns a directive, so in your case:

```
onComplete(DBManager.getUserByEmail(email)) {
  case Success(optUser) =>
    complete {optUser.map(UserWire(_)).getOrElse(StatusCodes.NotFound -> "User doesn't exist") }
  case Failure(_) =>
    complete { InternalServerError() }
}
```

Although I've never used it seems like Akka http has the [same method](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html).

Answer (score 1):

First thing. When you are building reactive application it is good to operate only on successful operations. Handling future fails need more resources than successful operations. Reactive version of `DBManager.getUserByEmail` should return `Future[Option[User]]`

When you have future just map result to Marshallable form or response.

```
get {
  (path("token") & parameters("email", "password")) { (email, password) =>
    complete {
      DBManager.getUserByEmail(email) map {
        case Some(user) =>
          UserWire(user)
        case None => 
          StatusCodes.NotFound -> "User doesn't exist"
      }
    }
  }
}
```